# how to use getItematposition() in recyclerview adapter as ListView

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecyclerViewAdapter` which fill my List with StoreName,image etc, I had model for listitems.ok, I'm migrating from a ListView to recylerview. i want to click on any item and get that items data(like Store name) and intent to another activity, now problem is that when i click on item it give wrong storename. but when i was using onItemclickListener that provide correct input. i will show u..

This my **RecyclerViewAdapter**.

```
 public class MyRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyRecyclerViewAdapter.DataObjectHolder> {
    private static String LOG_TAG = "MyRecyclerViewAdapter";
    private List<StoresItem> mDataset;
    private static MyClickListener myClickListener;
    Context context;

    Bitmap xx;

    public MyRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, List<StoresItem> myDataset)
    {
        mDataset = myDataset;
    }

    public static class DataObjectHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        TextView txtStoreName,txtDeliveryTime;
        ImageView storeImg;
        RatingBar ratingBar;



        public DataObjectHolder(View itemView)
        {


            super(itemView);
            txtStoreName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtStoreName);
            txtDeliveryTime = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtDeliveryTime);
            storeImg = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.storeImg);
            ratingBar=(RatingBar)itemView.findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Adding Listener");
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {

            myClickListener.onItemClick(getLayoutPosition(), v);
        }
    }



    public void setOnItemClickListener(MyClickListener myClickListener)
    {
        this.myClickListener = myClickListener;
    }



    @Override
    public DataObjectHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.storelist, parent, false);

        DataObjectHolder dataObjectHolder = new DataObjectHolder(view);
        return dataObjectHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(DataObjectHolder holder, int position)
    {

        ImageView storeImg;

        holder.txtStoreName.setText(mDataset.get(position).gettxtStoreName().toString());
        holder.txtDeliveryTime.setText(mDataset.get(position).gettxtDeliveryTime().toString());
        holder.ratingBar.setFocusable(false);


        int loader = R.drawable.image;

        String url = mDataset.get(position).getstoreImg().toString();

        ImageLoader imgLoader = new ImageLoader(context);

        imgLoader.DisplayImage(url,loader,holder.storeImg);


    }



    public void addItem(StoresItem dataObj, int index) {
        mDataset.add(dataObj);
        notifyItemInserted(index);
    }

    public void deleteItem(int index) {
        mDataset.remove(index);
        notifyItemRemoved(index);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataset.size();
    }

    public interface MyClickListener
    {
        public void onItemClick(int position, View v);
    }

    public Object getItem(int position)
    {
        return mDataset.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position)
    {
        return mDataset.indexOf(getItem(position));
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position)
    {
        return super.getItemViewType(position);
    }
}
```

This is my **StoreModel**.

```
public class StoresItem
{
        private String txtStoreName, txtDeliveryTime, storeImg;

        public StoresItem(String txtStoreName, String txtDeliveryTime,String storeImg)
        {

            this.txtStoreName = txtStoreName;
            this.txtDeliveryTime = txtDeliveryTime;
            this.storeImg = storeImg;

        }

    public String gettxtStoreName()
    {
        return txtStoreName;
    }

    public void settxtStoreName(String txtStoreName)
    {
        this.txtStoreName = txtStoreName;
    }

    public String gettxtDeliveryTime()
    {
        return txtDeliveryTime;
    }

    public void settxtDeliveryTime(String txtDeliveryTime)
    {
        this.txtDeliveryTime = txtDeliveryTime;
    }

    public String getstoreImg()
    {
        return storeImg;
    }

    public void setstoreImg(String storeImg)
    {
        this.storeImg = storeImg;
    }


}
```

And this is my Fragment where i using **onclickListner**.

```
 public class RecylerFragment extends Fragment
{

    ListView storeListView;
    List<StoresItem> storesItem;
    StoresListAdaptor adapter;
    String selectedStore;

    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;



    public static final String[] storeNameGrocery = new String[]
            {
                    "Value Store", "Grocery Mart", "Wild Water-Sadar Bazar", "Store99","Coco-Buzz", "Wild Water - Sector 46"
            };
    public static final String[] storeNameFresh = new String[]
            {
                    "Mother's Love", "The Flower Shop", "Flower N Emotions"
            };
    public static final String[] storeNameElectronics = new String[]
            {
                    "Molife-Sheetla Mata Road", "Apple Store- Shona Road", "Vandana Communication", "Samsung Store","JMD Mobile - Sector 14", "Sterling - Gurgaon"
            };
    public static final String[] storeNameVegetable = new String[]
            {
                    "Fortune Store", "Best Food - Mega Mall", "Sadar Bazar", "MTR Store","Coco-Buzz"
            };

    public static final String[] deliveryTime = new String[]
            {
                    "20min", "10min", "9min", "15min","30min", "1hr","20min","20min", "10min", "9min", "15min","30min", "1hr","20min" };


    private static final String KEY_POSITION="position";



    public static final String[] iconsUrl = new String[]
            {
                    "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/femfoyou/angry-birds/96/angry-bird-icon.png",
                    "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/rokey/the-blacy/96/grimace-icon.png",
                    "http://wcdn1.dataknet.com/static/resources/icons/set106/fec007de.png",
                    "http://cdn4.aptoide.com/imgs/7/6/e/76e0376928b8393227a150fbed5d6b4a_icon_96x96.png",
                    "http://vaivocabulary.com/vai/images/android.png",
                    "http://cdn4.aptoide.com/imgs/7/6/e/76e0376928b8393227a150fbed5d6b4a_icon_96x96.png",
                    "http://vaivocabulary.com/vai/images/android.png",
                    "http://wcdn1.dataknet.com/static/resources/icons/set106/fec007de.png",
            };


    public RecylerFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_recycler_view, container, false);


        Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
        String myString = bundle.getString("page_position");

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);


        RecyclerView.ItemDecoration itemDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(itemDecoration);

        // Code to Add an item with default animation
        //((MyRecyclerViewAdapter) mAdapter).addItem(obj, index);

        // Code to remove an item with default animation
        //((MyRecyclerViewAdapter) mAdapter).deleteItem(index);


        storesItem = new ArrayList<StoresItem>();

        if(myString.equals("999")) {
            for (int i = 0; i < storeNameGrocery.length; i++) {
                StoresItem item = new StoresItem(storeNameGrocery[i], "Delivery Time " + deliveryTime[i],iconsUrl[i]);
                storesItem.add(item);
            }
        }

        else if(myString.equals("888")) {
            for (int i = 0; i < storeNameFresh.length; i++) {
                StoresItem item = new StoresItem(storeNameFresh[i], "Delivery Time " + deliveryTime[i], iconsUrl[i]);
                storesItem.add(item);
            }
        }

        else if(myString.equals("777")) {
            for (int i = 0; i < storeNameElectronics.length; i++) {
                StoresItem item = new StoresItem(storeNameElectronics[i], "Delivery Time " + deliveryTime[i], iconsUrl[i]);
                storesItem.add(item);
            }
        }

        else if(myString.equals("666")) {
            for (int i = 0; i < storeNameVegetable.length; i++) {
                StoresItem item = new StoresItem(storeNameVegetable[i], "Delivery Time " + deliveryTime[i], iconsUrl[i]);
                storesItem.add(item);
            }
        }

        mAdapter = new MyRecyclerViewAdapter(getActivity(), storesItem);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);




        return rootView;
    }


    **@Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        ((MyRecyclerViewAdapter) mAdapter).setOnItemClickListener(new MyRecyclerViewAdapter.MyClickListener()
        {
        @Override
         public void onItemClick(int position, View v)
        {
            System.out.println(" Clicked on Item " + position);
            StoresItem storesItems = (StoresItem) ((MyRecyclerViewAdapter) mAdapter).getItem(position);
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            Intent in = new Intent(getActivity(), ProductActivity.class);
            args.putString("SelectedStoreName", storesItems.gettxtStoreName().toString());
            in.putExtras(args);
            startActivity(in);
        }
       });
    }**


    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
    }
}
```

okk...there is something wrong with recyclerviews-`onItemclicklister` because listviews - `onItemCLicklistner()`
  provide `Adapterview` and i can simply get Item by using `parent.getItematposition(position)` like this.

```
 storeListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            StoresItem storesItems = (StoresItem) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            Intent in = new Intent(getActivity(), ProductActivity.class);
            args.putString("SelectedStoreName", storesItems.gettxtStoreName().toString());
            in.putExtras(args);
            startActivity(in);

        }
    });
```

Can Any one tell me whats the reason why getWrong StoreName.??

Comment: Have you find a way how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You are using `myClickListener.onItemClick(getLayoutPosition(), v);` you have to use `myClickListener.onItemClick(getAdapterPosition(), v);`

Comment: No Improvement, it still Start Activity with Wrong StoreName (For inform you i m using ViewPager with 5 Fragments, onclick first item of first Framgment it fetch first Item of second Fragment of viewPagger, same happen with other item click, and some time get Correct StoreName, and Some Time (outofboundexception)) , Dont know whats wrong..???